# How to include other configuration files in web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

I need to define many servlets, but I don't want to write the configuration all in the web.xml.

Can I define some servlet configuration files, and include them in web.xml? Or is there any other way to split a web.xml to multi files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Servlet 3.0 specification provides a new annotation, `@WebServlet`, that may be used to declare servlets in the code without the need for the web.xml. See Section 8.1.1 of the [Servlet 3.0 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) and review the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) for more details.

```
@WebServlet("/myServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    //...
}
```

Additionally, Servlet 3.0 introduced the concept of web fragments, which addresses your second question about splitting the `web.xml` into multiple files. These fragments can contain a portion (or all) of the web deployment descriptor by including a `META-INF/web-fragment.xml` file and/or servlet annotations in jar files within your web module's `WEB-INF/lib` directory. See Section 8.2 of the [Servlet 3.0 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The Servlet 3.0 specification allows for declaring servlets through Java annotations - so no entries required within the `web.xml` file.  Other than that, I'm not aware of any "include" functionality.