# Servlet Mapping. Web.xml

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

In java web application is it possible to map servlets in files that are not "web.xml"?
I mean. I will need to map over a hundred servelts and web.xml would be dificult to deal with.
Dividing the mappings in several file by cathegory would be great.

If there is some way please would you tell me how?.

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include other configuration files in web.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380440/how-to-include-other-configuration-files-in-web-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about dividing web.xml file. But you can achieve your task by defining your servlets through Java Annotations instead of defining them in web.xml. The [Servlet 3.0 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) provides a new annotation **@WebServlet** that can be used to declare your servlets.

Comment: Hi rizz86. Annotations seems to work fine. Thank you very much. Your answer was  very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Servlet 3.0 provides **Pluggability Feature** which allows you to define web artifacts using:

- `Web Fragments`. The libraries inside `WEB-INF/lib` can have `META-INF/web-fragment.xml` which can define part of full deployment descriptor.
- `Annotations`. You can define Servlet, Filters and Listeners using @WebServlet, @WebFilter and @WebListener annotation.